# How to scatter plot 1D numpy array as 2D

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib

```
output_directory = "LITE"+'/results/' + "ArrowHead" + '/'
model = keras.models.load_model(output_directory+'best_model.hdf5')
concat_tsne_model_results = []
for i in range(len([layer for layer in model.layers if 'hybrid' in layer.name])):
    filters_train = [layer for layer in model.layers if 'hybrid' in layer.name][i].get_weights()[0]


    concat_tsne_model_results.append(filters_train)

concat_tsne_model = np.vstack(concat_tsne_model_results)
print("result:", concat_tsne_model.shape)
```

result: (438, 1, 1)

Now, how can I make scatter plot this with using matplotlib pyplot

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, do you mind to have a look at [ask] and the try to produce a [mcve]?

Comment: Please also think carefully what you want to put on the x-axis, and what on the y-axis. Maybe `ax.scatter(range(len(concat_tsne_model)), concat_tsne_model.squeeze())`? Or `sns.stripplot(y=concat_tsne_model.squeeze())`? Or ...?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I want to give this matrix int TSNE and I want to get 2D array then I plot it, this is the goal here. range(len(concat_tsne_model)) this one is not useful here